# Converting file content to different format (ASP .NET 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to return data from my API in different formats. I'm using standard formatters and few custom formatters. Everything works fine when I try to convert data like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(MyEntity entity)
{
    return Ok(entity);
}
```

Problem is, when I try to do the same for files, I can't get content formatted properly.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Form.Files[0] : null;
        if (file == null)
            return BadRequest();

        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        Request.ContentType.Remove(0);
        Request.ContentType = file.ContentType;

        return Ok(content);
    }
```

Is there any way around it? I think I should use formatters somehow manually, but can't figure it out. I also tried overriding Ok method, but Formatters on OkObjectResult were empty.

Input file test.json:

```
{
    "attr1": "hi",
    "attr2": "there",
}
```

Expected output as xml:

```
<MyEntity xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Application.Models">
    <Attr1>hi</Attr2>
    <Attr2>there</Attr2>
</MyEntity>
```

Output received:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{
    "attr1": "hi",
    "attr2": "there"
}</string>
```

Comment: First of all: You seem to be under the impression that you can automagically change the actual content type by assigning a different content type designator to the request object. It does *not* work that way.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what is being returned, why it's wrong and an example of what you're expecting.

Comment: BTW: It's common practice to call the second snippet's method "PostAsync".

Comment: @Fildor Apologies, I forgot to delete that part after I tried to make it work somehow. Anyway, do you have any idea how to use the formatters for this problem, if it's even possible?

Comment: If you want to for example change XML to JSON, you need to actually change the content format. So you'd need some sort of data deserialization/serialization. Just changing a string that says "Content is XY" is not enough.

Comment: Yeah I understand that part, but if ASP.NET is able to deserialize body content to MyEntity (xml/json/...), my question is if I'm able to use this logic for deserializing MyEntity from file content.

Comment: I am afraid not (at least that I am aware of). You'd need to do this explicitly.

Comment: @phuzi there is my expectations, but I would want it to work for different formats too. https://pastebin.com/TaNA3SRu

Comment: @MSL You'd be better off putting that extra detail in the question.

Comment: Updated your question with the extra info

Comment: Looks like you're trying to convert JSON to XML. You'll have to parse the JSON to a DTO/model and then return the DTO so that it can be serialized automatically. You're currently just returning a string hence the string XML element.

Comment: Few comments above I talked about that, the input would not be always json, it could be xml, maybe even other formats, I found out about formatters, but can't make it work with file content, deserialization and serialization managed by framework works fine, tho I'm searching for possibility to reuse that functionality for file contents, if it's possible.

Comment: If you want the output to be automatically serialised properly then you will need to return a DTO to do this you will need to manually load/parse your text files, there's nothing that will do this automatically for you though. You will need to know beforehand whether it's JSON, XML or some other custom format. ASP.Net can do it when deserialising request content because the content-type header will identify the format of the contained text.

Comment: Okay, thats response I was kind of expecting, I was looking if I could save myself some work. Thank you

Comment: You're probably looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#content-negotiation

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    var file = Request.Form.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Form.Files[0] : null;
    if (file == null)
        return BadRequest();

    var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
    
    return File(stream, file.ContentType);
}
```

Comment: This returns the file content in content type of the file, not in Accept header